# Using mvn aem-project-archetype in AEM 6.2 does not resolve the core bundle - javax.inject cannot be resolved

Tags: osgi, aem, osgi-bundle, sling

I'm trying to build a new project using mvn aem-project-archetype (https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-project-archetype)  and on deploy the core bundle shows status as "Installed" but cannot be Active showing the error

```
javax.inject, version=[0.0,1) -- Cannot be resolved
```

[image]

I tried to add the dependencies as suggested here (https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-project-archetype/issues/59)

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-atinject_1.0_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

and also tried all solutions as listed here (http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__fikl-ive_just_updatedfro.html) but they did not resolve.

Appreciate any help here.

Comment: Have you written <Embed-Dependency><Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=false</Embed-Dependency></Embed-Dependency> in maven-bundle-plugin instrutions

Comment: Thanks. Tried it, but the same issue. The below did not Activate the bundle:                                                                                             <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.3</version>
  <inherited>true</inherited>
  <configuration>
    <instructions>
      <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=false</Embed-Dependency>
    </instructions>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research here's some solutions for the above:

1. Comment "@Inject" in HelloWorldModel.java . This may not be ideal, but if you are not planning on using Sling Models, then this will work.

   ```
   @Model(adaptables=Resource.class)
   public class HelloWorldModel {

   //@Inject
   private SlingSettingsService settings;

   //@Inject @Named("sling:resourceType") @Default(values="No resourceType")
   protected String resourceType;
   ```
2. Use [ACS's Lazybones AEM Template](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/lazybones-aem-templates) instead of Archetype 10 if you will be using AEM 6.1 or higher. This is the recommended template to use with AEM whihc is more sophisticated and up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

Add Import-Package tag for "**javax.inject**" with version "**0.0.0,***" under "**org.apache.felix**" plugin tag like below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
          <!-- <Embed-Dependency>
                artifactId1,artifactId2;inline=true
          </Embed-Dependency> -->

          <!-- Import any version of javax.inject, to allow running on multiple versions of AEM -->
          <Import-Package>javax.inject;version=0.0.0,*</Import-Package>

          <Sling-Model-Packages>com.xyz.sample_test_impl.core</Sling-Model-Packages>
        </instructions>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to sync your dependencies list with the following [official sample project](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-sample-we-retail). In fact, it helped for me just after adding

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

to general *pom.xml* and

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

to its child *../core/pom.xml*